# Angular2: implementing the tabs

Tags: angular, plunker

I want to implement tabs on my page and therefore went through this tutorial

https://dzone.com/articles/learning-angular-2-creating-a-tabs-component but somehow its not working for me with Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/jwBB7jd8KDXmndGBz4ZN?p=preview

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  template: '<div [hidden]="!active" class="pane">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./tab.component.css']
})
export class Tab{
  @Input('tabTitle') title: string;
  @Input() active = false;


}
```

And Tabs Component:

```
  import { Component, OnInit,ContentChildren,QueryList ,AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { Tab } from './tab.component.ts';

    @Component({
      selector: 'tabs',
      template: `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [hidden]='true' (click)="selectTab(tab)" [class.active]="tab.active">
        <a>{{tab.title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ng-content></ng-content>`,
      styleUrls: ['./tabs.component.css']
    })
    export class Tabs implements AfterContentInit{
      @ContentChildren(Tab) tabs: QueryList<Tab>;



     ngAfterContentInit() {
      let activeTabs = this.tabs.filter((tab)=>tab.active);

      if(activeTabs.length === 0) {
        this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
      }
    }

    selectTab(tab: Tab){
      this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
      tab.active = true;
    }
    }
```

Please note : its first time i am working with Plunker, so please excuse me.
I hope someone can help me with this .

Thanks.

Comment: Improved Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Mdj9llvGiEyMBmbSRoo7?p=preview but it throws an error about `Zone is not defined` (also in a new Angular2 TS Plunker template)

Answer (score 4):

I have a very easy solution
home.component.ts

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li [ngClass]=" {'active-tab': tab==1 }"><a (click)=" tab = 1 " href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 1</a></li>
<li [ngClass]=" {'active-tab': tab==2 }"><a (click)=" tab = 2 " href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 2</a></li>
<li [ngClass]=" {'active-tab': tab==3 }"><a (click)=" tab = 3 " href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 3</a></li>df
</ul>

<div class="tab-panel" id="tabPanel1" *ngIf="tab==1">
    ABC TAB 1
</div>
<div class="tab-panel" id="tabPanel2" *ngIf="tab==2">
    ABC TAB 2
</div>
<div class="tab-panel" id="tabPanel3" *ngIf="tab==3">
    ABC TAB 3
</div>
```

This is very easy without using any third party component
if you want to active any tab on page load
then assign value to "tab" variable

```
home.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  tab: number = 3;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not loaded.
You need to set your plunker as angular 2 app when you create it.